# MySQL how to insert

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables here for example table A and table B, how can i insert data when both of the tables consist of foreign key of each other? like table A got an attribute is foreign key references of table B, and table B got an attribute is foreign key references of table A

```
create table abc
(ID varchar(10),
subID varchar(10),
primary key (ID),
foreign key (subID) references def(SubID)
)

create table def
(SubID varchar(10),
ID varchar(10),
primary key (SubID),
foreign key (ID) references abc(ID)
)
```

somehow like this(i skipped other various informations)

Comment: Can you provide a 'real-world' example?

Comment: I think it is bad database design.

Comment: Yes, when this happens your design is wrong.

Comment: is this totally got wrong that only can change the design to fix it? or is there any other way to insert data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible in your current design.

If you really have the need to do insert with cross dependency over the two tables, remove the one foreign key. Then you can do an insert on table ABC and then DEF.

I also think your DB design is incorrect.

Comment: after delete the foreign key field is it need to use something like 'alter table... add constraint... foreign key...references'?